# How do you call arguments?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I want to print out the arguments first.

```
# I want to call it here.
print("Which of these values is the highest?")

# Without needing to print this one below. How do I call the argument at the end?
print(4, 8, 2)

def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return num1
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
        return num2
    else:
        return num3


print(max_num(4, 8, 2), "is the highest value.")
```

I know I can just make a variable and change the whole thing but is it possible here?

Comment: Are there always only 3 numbers or function should accept many numbers as input?

Comment: why did I not think of that lmao, thank u very much

Comment: why don't you assing to variables first - and then you can use then in any places. OR better keep it as list in variable - then you can use standard `max(list)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use many times the assign to variable

```
# --- functions ---

def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return num1
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
        return num2
    else:
        return num3

# --- main ---

n1 = 4
n2 = 8
n3 = 2

print("Which of these values is the highest?")
print(n1, n2, n3)
print(max_num(n1, n2, n3), "is the highest value.")
```

---

**BTW:** If you will keep it as list then you can use standard `max(list)` instead of your function

```
numbers = [4, 8, 2]

print("Which of these values is the highest?")
print(*numbers)  # use * to unpack values from list and use as separated values in `print()`
print(max(numbers), "is the highest value.")
```